# Posting input textbox the email php

Tags: php, forms, email

Hi Im trying to build a simple sign up form one where a person enters their email and submits.

This input is then emailed to the owner of the site, I thought the code below would work however it isnt?

Html code:

```
  <form id="signup-form" method="post" action="send.php">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
        </form>
```

php script:

```
 <?php

// Change this to YOUR address
  $recipient = 'email@address.co.uk';
  $email = $_POST['email'];

?>
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: use `isset` function `if(isset($_POST['email'])){//put your code here and echo $email;}` and make sure you are posting to `send.php` file

Comment: I can't see anything that would send email here. Did you paste full code?

Comment: No code here to send an email

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code as it is only stores two variables, and doesn't actually do anything with them. For the built-in PHP function for sending emails, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Something along the lines of:

```
mail($recipient, 'Email Subject', $_POST['email']);
```

would work, assuming the inputted data is validated correctly and an email has in fact been submitted.

**UPDATE:**

This file works fine and sends an email based on the behaviour you have described - running on both a local and hosted (1and1) server. Apologies for not being able to provide a solution to your problem.

```
<?php

$recipient = 'email@server.domain';

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    mail($recipient, 'Email Subject', $_POST['email']);
}

?>

<form id="signup-form" method="post" action="this_file.php">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi this still hasnt worked? Im new tp php and not sure what im doing wrong.... :/

Comment: Hi @Dave, did you copy directly from mine? If so I've just corrected a typo and it might be worth trying again..

Comment: Sorry for obvious questions but, like I said, is an email definitely being set? And are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: an email is being set within the input box and no error messages, but still no email?

Comment: And, again sorry for the obvious question, but what have you set `$recipient` to?

Comment: $recipient has been set to my email

Comment: Good.. Hmm exact same code is working fine for me, can I ask what type of server you are running this on?

Comment: its hosted with godaddy? not sure how I can find out what server?

Comment: Okay great no that's what I was asking. Perhaps a possible source of the problem would be to do with GoDaddy's server settings and privileges regarding sending emails. If you have access to a local server I suggest testing the same code on that and seeing if it makes a difference - like I said I'm running practically the exact same code and it's working fine, so I'll provide a copy of that in the answer but I'm afraid I'll be of little help otherwise.